# Parental Control for Youtube Android

Tags: android, monitoring, youtube, parental-control

I need an app for Android that's able to monitor/log the titles of watched Youtube videos on the child's mobile device with the time spent on each video and when it was watched. And this log can be accessed remotely by the parent.

Also I need it to be able to block all videos with ability to add exceptions for some channels/videos. And in case the child needs to view a blocked video, he/she can request permission from parent by a request permission button when parent is away (and parent can accept/reject that request remotely and set some time limit for that permission, like [Kaspersky SafeKids](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaspersky.safekids&hl=en) does with apps).

Price: Any
Android version: 5.0

Comment: What you are asking for seems practically impossible. YouTube Kids perhaps is the best answer I can think of, apart from, say, parental filter on routers for redirects to pages you do not want viewed.

Comment: If you can't find this kind of app, your best bet might be to get a good parental control app that will do something similar with YouTube in the browser. I know many parental control apps allow you to, see time spent, restrict certain websites etc.

Comment: I think the YouTube watch history is the only thing that really comes close.  Of course, that can be purged by a savvy kid.